# How do I project the Earth globe on a flat plane with minimal distortion?

Tags: mathematics, maps, projection

- I want to build a game where the game map is the planet Earth.
- The game map needs to be on a 2d plane, with the Earth texture projected on it
- If the player walks endelessly in one direction, it should just run laps around the Earth.
- I want to split the map in several small tiles and Load on Demand as the player walks

I'm not sure how to best solve this problem. What Map Projection do I use? From my research it seems like most maping apps like Google Maps, or OSM etc use variations of the [Mercator Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection). I can't use that because, while the player would be able lap around the earth when walking east, he wouldn't be able to walk north. It won't tile vertically.

Then the [Peirce Quincuncial Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_quincuncial_projection) looked promising, it's a perfectly tiled projection. But the problem then becomes distortion is too extreme here. Some places don't look the same. I can live with a tiny bit of distortion, but this is too much.

Then I found another common solution was using a [Truncated Icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron) (probably subdivided into smaller tiles for LoD). This looks like the best alternative so far. But now my problem is I'm not sure exactly how I would work out the algorithm to take tiles from the 3d Icosahedron and tile them side by side on a 2d plane. That would look like this: [image: 4]]

How would I stretch it to fill the holes?

Is there some other obvious solution I'm missing? How do games like Pokémon Go do this kind of thing?

Comment: You might find [this previous question on managing planet-scale level content](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/108667/39518) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favourite projection is that of Buckminster Fuller.

[image]

You just need to implement some fancy wrap-around that let's you jump from the edge of the map to another edge.

But the distortion is very low: land mass sizes are preserved.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dymaxion_map